# How to connect together Simulink/MATLAB to Python via TCP/IP?

Tags: python, matlab, sockets, tcp, simulink

I want to connect together **MATLAB/Simulink** and **Python API inside from Visual Components** software. I want to share information in run-time/step-by-step update. There is some kind of connection, but it occurs all of a sudden and stops, it is also not step by step and furthermore the port has a very different address other than that being given.

The Simulink screenshot can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azJRn.png). While the Python code is the following

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from vcScript import *

import socket
import sys
import time

# start simulation
# -init TCP-Server
# -wait for connection
def createTCPIPServer(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT):

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.settimeout(30)
  s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  s.listen(20)

  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print('Connection address:', addr)
  conn.setblocking(1)
  return conn

# at each simulation step
# read and write to TCP
def readTCP(conn):
  BUFFER_SIZE = 1  # Normally 1024 
  data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

  return data

def writeTCP(conn,data):
  conn.sendall(data)  # echo

# end simulation 
# close connection 
def closeTCP(conn):
  print("Close connection in 5 sec")
  time.sleep(10)
  conn.close()
  print("connection closed")

def OnSignal( signal ):
  pass

def OnRun():
  #createTCPIPClient(4112)
  conn = createTCPIPServer('127.0.0.1', 5005)
  while 1:
      data = readTCP(conn)
      if not data: break
      print("received data:", data)
      writeTCP(conn,data)
  closeTCP(conn)
  pass
```

**When in Simulink the *TCP/IP Receive* block is uncommented:** Running on both sides, Python side waits and after timeout it fails. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eik80.png)

**When in Simulink the *TCP/IP Receive* block is commented:** Running on both sides, Python side waits and after timeout it suddenly give all the received values. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsw47.png)

I want a proper connection with output in run-time/step-by-step so to process it in Visual Components. How to get this desired stable output?

Comment: Did you try it with UDP? Perhaps the TCP connection is waiting for some sort of "ack" packet that never comes.

Comment: The TCP connection is already connected I think as you can see in the screenshots (at least for the case when in Simulink the TCP/IP Receive block is commented). And no I didnt try with UDP. I hope you mean only UDP-UDP connection. I will look for it too but I would still prefer TCP/IP.